# IoC convention registration and multiple interfaces on a class

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container

Say we are having multiple interfaces on a class

```
Class1: IInterface1, Interface2 {}
```

In cases we want to dependency inject implementation of these into seperate classes using IInterface1/IInterface2

```
Class Foo1(IInterface1 interface1) {}

Class Foo2(IInterface2 interface2) {}
```

We would have registrations for both of these interfaces in the container

```
container.Register<IInterface1,Class1>();
container.Register<IInterface2,Class1>();
```

Currently what I do is read the interfaces from the class type information and register the interfaces that are on them to the class.(using reflection). There is no convention here though

How are such scenarios usually handled. Any specific naming conventions that we can use for these scenarios or is it enough to register interface's by reading the class type information?

Comment: I see no inherent problem with registering multiple interfaces to one class. Do you have a problem with it?

Comment: I am more looking for to how would you follow a convention for this. Is it really a convention to read interfaces from class and register against it? As opposed to having a similar name convention like IClass1 and Class1

Comment: It's up to you to define a convention that makes sense in your code base. I don't think this question should have a definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wanted to check if there was any conventions followed for such situations as these tend to occur commonly. So for now I think it is good enough to register back the interfaces from the class definition.

Comment: Just to answer my own question, this is what I currently follow
http://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/ioc-registration-by-convention/